# SQL: Select wordpress posts with given text string and add a custom field to them?

Tags: custom-field, sql, phpmyadmin

I want to select all wordpress posts that have a certain text string.

Then to add a custom field to all those posts.

Here is what I figured out so far but it doesn't work

```
INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
SELECT ID AS post_id, 
       'customer_reviews' AS meta_key, 
       'On_or_delete' AS meta_value
FROM   wp_posts 
WHERE  ID IS IN
       (SELECT post_id 
        FROM wp_posts
        WHERE post_content LIKE '%Customer Reviews%')
       AND post_type = 'post';
```

Anyone know how to do this please?

Comment: If you use PHPMyAdmin you can easily create the MySQL query you need to `select all posts where post_content like 'something'` and do a PHP loop to add the custom fields. If this is the only issue, the Question is *off-topic* (pure PHP and/or pure MySQL).

Comment: What a vague answer. Your vagueness is strange in the case of answering a technical question that specifically states what the intended solution is to be. I've said I know how to do one part, and I've actually got further:

Comment: It's not an Answer. The Comments area of a Question&Answer site is used to provide feedback and request clarifications about the Q, so it can be improved. Check the pages [about] and [help].

Comment: Apologies. I have updated the question with more information and a clearer picture of what I've tried to do. I'm new to this so you have to forgive my misunderstanding of both SQL and WP. Thanks.

Comment: The WP way of doing this is with a custom plugin with one DB query (get post ID's where content LIKE) and a loop with a simple [`update_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta). If your Question is simply how to correct this SQL query, I believe it's off-topic here, it's being close-voted as such, and candidate to migration to [so].

Comment: @brasofilo I got it. The lady below answered and I was close already. Thanks guys. Welcome to edit the post title to be more search friendly as I wasn't sure what to put as title. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go (you're really close):

```
INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
SELECT ID AS post_id,
'customer_reviews' AS meta_key, 
'On_or_delete' AS meta_value
FROM wp_posts WHERE wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%Customer Reviews%'
   AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post';
```

`

Edit:
You could also just change IS IN to IN. I rewrote the from part of the query since a subquery was unnecessary though.